# Angular: How can i push an observable to a list

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I get an Error message that i cant push an undefined variable to my list.
This is my code in the component.ts

```
for (const file of this.allFiles) {
  this.uploadFileService
    .validate(file)
    .subscribe(  valid => {
      this.validList.push(valid);
    })
}
```

This is my Service:

```
validate(file: File): Observable<boolean> {
      const data: FormData = new FormData();
      data.append('file', file);
      return this.http.post<boolean>(`${this.url}/validate`,data);
    }
```

How can I push to the list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error if you do not initialize the array (`[]`) first before pushing. Please declare the variable `validList: Array<any> = []` at the top of the component before pushing data inside.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular';
  validList: Array<any> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.validList.push(true);
  }
}
```

[Issue replicated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgvbwy)

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgrixt)